# Uploading large file using rest service wcf through postman

Tags: wcf, postman

I'm developing an website by .net mvc. I created an wcf service in my web project. I'm trying to upload file through this service. I'm not able to upload large file by this. My code is here. Please help me.

My Service Interface

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "AddDiscount", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        Result AddDiscount([MessageParameter(Name = "data")] Stream data);
```

Here data receiving image and other parameters.

```
public Result AddDiscount(Stream data)
        {
            Result objResult = new Result();
            TBL_DISCOUNT_MASTER objDiscount = new TBL_DISCOUNT_MASTER();

            long? PostedDiscountId;

            try
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
                var str = reader.ReadToEnd();
                objDiscount = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TBL_DISCOUNT_MASTER>(str);


                Image dd = objCamel.byteArrayToImage(objDiscount.DISCOUNT_LOGO);
                string FileName = string.Concat(PostedDiscountId, "_logo.jpg");
                var path = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Discount"), FileName);
                dd.Save(path);

                dd = objCamel.byteArrayToImage(objDiscount.DISCOUNT_IMAGE);
                FileName = string.Concat(PostedDiscountId, "_background.jpg");
                path = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Discount"), FileName);
                dd.Save(path);

                dd = objQRCode.GetQRCode(PostedDiscountId.ToString()); ;
                FileName = string.Concat(PostedDiscountId, "_qr.jpg");
                path = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Discount"), FileName);
                dd.Save(path);

                objResult.SUCCESS = 1;
                objResult.MESSAGE = "Thank you for adding a discount offer. Please wait for admin approval.";


                return objResult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                objResult.SUCCESS = 2;
                objResult.MESSAGE = "Failed - " + ex.Message;
                return objResult;
            }

        }
```

My web.config

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" name="httpsBinding" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
              </security>
          </binding>
          <binding name="Default">
              <security mode="Transport" />
          </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Zahhab.Services.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
    <endpoint address="ZahhabService" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Zahhab.Services.IService1"/>

  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: _"...I'm not able to upload large file by this..."_ - isn't helpful.  Any error message?

Comment: That's not an _error message_.  Besides, we can harly access your computer

Comment: 413 Request entity too large. @MickyD

Answer (score 0):

By default, WCF allows you to upload up to 29,3 MB file size. You can modify this by changing the following in web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="40960000" />  <!-- allow up to 40 mb -->
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: how much is your file size ? @SabbirAhmedAnik

Comment: 500 MB maximum. I'm using  <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"> but still not working. @Houssam Hamdan

Comment: @SabbirAhmedAnik the file is big for a wcf service to handle i believe. did you consider other alternatives ?

Comment: No, I didn't try other alternatives. Would you please suggest me any other alternatives? Although my client requirement is WCF. @Houssam Hamdan

Comment: Would you please help me? @Houssam Hamdan

Comment: What exception you currently having ? write the full stacktrace somewhere to read it please @SabbirAhmedAnik

Comment: Actually, I have a service function for uploading file with some text data. I am testing it from postman. I tried in two way. One is form-data in body and the other is raw string data. In both case postman showing 413 File too large. Please see the error details here.                                        https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B93PLu0yyfIRdE9nRFFINndmODQ/view?usp=sharing @Houssam Hamdan

Comment: the file is 512 kb small. please share your web.config as such

Comment: Please see my web.config file from here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B93PLu0yyfIRX1l0dHhzMXB6VFk/view?usp=sharing @Houssam Hamdan

Comment: @SabbirAhmedAnik your web.config is ok. I believe this error is coming from entity framework. Try stopping the code related to data access and try to upload again, Put a breakpoint and make sure the file correctly arrived to server. waiting for you

Comment: Thank you Houssam Hamdan. It was actually configuration problem. I figured it out. Thank you for your try.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. I've just added following section beside existing in my web.config file. The complete configuration is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
              <binding receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" name="httpsBinding" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
                  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                      <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
                  </security>
              </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding transferMode="Streamed" name="webBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="0" receiveTimeout="01:30:00" sendTimeout="01:30:00">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="my service name" behaviorConfiguration="Default">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webBinding" contract="my contract" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```